Are the selector in a Headless Service and serviceName in Stateful set redundant?
Learner Question:
In a Headless Service we can specify a selector to select the Pods for which to create the DNS SRV records.
In a StatefulSet we can specify a governing service with the serviceName entry, which should be the headless service that we created with a selector above.  This will also have a selector.
If the StatefulSet specifies the governing service, why does the governing service need a selector?  And what happens if they don't match each other (i.e. the two selectors select different groups of Pods)?


why does the governing service need a selector?
what happens if they don't match

Assigning the service to the StatefulSet does not automatically update the service's selector to match the StatefulSet selector. Likewise, if the service uses a wrong selector; name lookup to the <pod>.<governing service domain> will fail.
